# Access AWS Paramstore from Springboot app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
        <awsSpring.version>2.3.0</awsSpring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${awsSpring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When i run the demo application with this pom i am getting

```
io.awspring.cloud.paramstore.AwsParamStorePropertySources$AwsParameterPropertySourceNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.mode
```

It is trying to access paramstore which is what i want but when I change the springboot version to 2.4.4 and spring-cloud.version to 2020.0.2 and I run the same application now It is not trying to connect to aws paramstore.

Can someone explain how i can access paramstore if I upgrade to springboot to  2.4.4

Comment: lol...your XML code snippet above actually does "run" :>)

Comment: @user2975699 is this solved yet? can you share the solution here?

Answer (score 3):

In spring-cloud 2020.0.0 (aka Ilford), the bootstrap phase is no longer enabled by default. In order enable it you need an additional dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, starting at spring-cloud-aws 2.3, allows import default aws parameterstore keys using `spring.config.import=aws-parameterstore:`

You can find this information at the end of the following section https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.0/reference/html/index.html#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-parameter-store

Comment: Should be `aws-parameterstore:` instead `aws-parameter-store:`